# Rails 3.2 with Ajax implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am a beginner with Ruby on Rails. I have been able to build a small application with the help of ROR.
I want to fetch and load some of my data without loading the whole page. On click of different links, data should be uploaded in the respective div. I am trying to provide :remote=>true property on the link. But this property is not rendering an attribute properly.
After following multiple links on Rails with Ajax, I found that in view links should be given as:

```
<%= link_to cateogary.cateogary_name, :controller => "cateogaries", :action => "show_async", :id => cateogary_id, :remote => true %>
```

This should be converted to:

```
<a href="/cateogaries/12/show_async data-remote=true">
```

While, this is converted to:

```
<a href="/cateogaries/12/show_async?remote=true">
```

What could be its probable reason?
Please forward some good link which provides complete Ajax implementation in ROR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails is recognizing `:remote => true` as a parameter for the URL. Try this:

```
<%= link_to cateogary.cateogary_name, { :controller => "cateogaries", :action => "show_async", :id => cateogary_id }, :remote => true %>
```

Or maybe this:

```
<%= link_to cateogary.cateogary_name, "/cateogaries/#{cateogary_id}/show_async", :remote => true %>
```

Additionally, I'd recommend you to read [this](http://dharmaprogramming.wordpress.com/2012/06/13/dont-send-javascript-as-an-ajax-response/) (and also check the links).